# How to create a shibboleth auth saml request in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, shibboleth

We have installed shibboleth sp and idp on our local server and login is successful using ldap connection. Now problem.is that shibboleth sp used *.sso filter in iis, we want to remove it and make a c sharp code stuf which create a saml request to shibboleth idp . Is there any possible ways for it.

Thanks

Comment: @johnny5 this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat I should have been more clear in my original comment, and stated that If the OP Added a [MCVE],  and formatted their question in a way which asked a concise question.  Then, it would be more suitable for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Finally we have got it.
Suppose we have call a action method on login click.

```
    public ActionResult submitresult()
    {

        AuthRequest req = new AuthRequest();
        return Redirect("http://myshibboleth.idp.com/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?SAMLRequest=" + Server.UrlEncode(req.GetRequest(AuthRequest.AuthRequestFormat.Base64)));           
    }
```

Here is my AuthRequest class.

```
public class Certificate
{
    public X509Certificate2 cert;

    public void LoadCertificate()
    {
        string certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----certificate data -----END CERTIFICATE-----";
        cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
        cert.Import(StringToByteArray(certificate));
    }

    public void LoadCertificate(byte[] certificate)
    {
        cert = new X509Certificate2();
        cert.Import(certificate);
    }

    private byte[] StringToByteArray(string st)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[st.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)st[i];
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}

public class Response
{
    private XmlDocument xmlDoc;

    private Certificate certificate;
    public Response()
    {

        certificate = new Certificate();
        certificate.LoadCertificate();
    }

    public void LoadXml(string xml)
    {
        xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDoc.XmlResolver = null;
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
    }

    public void LoadXmlFromBase64(string response)
    {
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        LoadXml(enc.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(response)));
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        bool status = true;

        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("ds", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
        manager.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
        manager.AddNamespace("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ds:Signature", manager);

        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

        status &= signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate.cert, true);

        var notBefore = NotBefore();
        status &= !notBefore.HasValue || (notBefore <= DateTime.Now);

        var notOnOrAfter = NotOnOrAfter();
        status &= !notOnOrAfter.HasValue || (notOnOrAfter > DateTime.Now);

        return status;
    }

    public DateTime? NotBefore()
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
        manager.AddNamespace("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");

        var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:Conditions", manager);
        string value = null;
        if (nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0 && nodes[0] != null && nodes[0].Attributes != null && nodes[0].Attributes["NotBefore"] != null)
        {
            value = nodes[0].Attributes["NotBefore"].Value;
        }
        return value != null ? DateTime.Parse(value) : (DateTime?)null;
    }

    public DateTime? NotOnOrAfter()
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
        manager.AddNamespace("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");

        var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:Conditions", manager);
        string value = null;
        if (nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0 && nodes[0] != null && nodes[0].Attributes != null && nodes[0].Attributes["NotOnOrAfter"] != null)
        {
            value = nodes[0].Attributes["NotOnOrAfter"].Value;
        }
        return value != null ? DateTime.Parse(value) : (DateTime?)null;
    }

    public string GetNameID()
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("ds", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
        manager.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
        manager.AddNamespace("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");

        XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:Subject/saml:NameID", manager);
        return node.InnerText;
    }
}

public class AuthRequest
{
    public string id;
    private string issue_instant;


    public enum AuthRequestFormat
    {
        Base64 = 1
    }

    public AuthRequest()
    {

        id = "_" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        issue_instant = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    }

    public string GetRequest(AuthRequestFormat format)
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

            using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xws))
            {
                xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "AuthnRequest", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
                xw.WriteAttributeString("ID", id);
                xw.WriteAttributeString("Version", "2.0");
                xw.WriteAttributeString("IssueInstant", issue_instant);
                xw.WriteAttributeString("ProtocolBinding", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST");
                xw.WriteAttributeString("AssertionConsumerServiceURL", "http://localhost/SAML2/POST"); // service provider url to consume token . it should be post method
                xw.WriteAttributeString("Destination", "http://myshibboleth.idp.com/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO");

                //xw.WriteAttributeString("AssertionConsumerServiceURL", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssertionConsumerServiceURL"]);
                //xw.WriteAttributeString("Destination", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Destination"]);


                xw.WriteStartElement("saml", "Issuer", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
                xw.WriteString("http://localhost");  // service provider home url
                xw.WriteEndElement();

                xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "NameIDPolicy", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");

                xw.WriteAttributeString("AllowCreate", "true");
                xw.WriteEndElement();

                //xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "RequestedAuthnContext", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
                //xw.WriteAttributeString("Comparison", "exact");

                //xw.WriteStartElement("saml", "AuthnContextClassRef", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
                //xw.WriteString("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport");
                //xw.WriteEndElement();

                xw.WriteEndElement(); // RequestedAuthnContext


            }

            if (format == AuthRequestFormat.Base64)
            {

                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
                using (var output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var zip = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        zip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray());
                    return base64;
                    //return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}